# Wordpress paragraphs are duplicating

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble on the website: http://www.artteen.com.br/concursos/

I didn't develop this website, but currently I am responsible for the maintenance. I already solved a lot of problems and currently have a problem with content duplicating.

The WordPress installation for the website somehow is duplicating the first or the last paragraph.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

A bad solution that I found is putting display:none so only the duplication is visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably start by de activating all plugins and re-activate each, one by one, to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I deactivated and re-activated all the plugins and the issue persists, deleted and published the page again and the issue persists.

Comment: did you de-activate all plugin, tried to write and then re-activated? the idea being to see if it's a plugin (generally it is) causing this… and help identify which